# How to have two local folders sync bidirectionally and automatically on OS X?

Tags: git, svn, unison

I am in a workflow where I regularly have to install an application locally, and then sync the folders of that application now installed locally with an SVN repository hosted in another folder on my computer.

I have successfully created this workflow using the [hardlink](https://github.com/selkhateeb/hardlink) command-line utility. To do this I first deleted the folders in my local installation of the application, and then used the hardlink command line utility to link the SVN repo folders with the folders that were then created in the local installation directory.

The problem with this workflow is that it is very slow and requires manual input, which doesn't work if I need to repeat this process regularly (which I do).

I have tried other bidirectional file synchronization programs (Unison etc), but they seem to not cover the need that I have, where the synchronization happens automatically without the need to run the given program.

Based on this, I am thinking of writing a bash script that will automate this process for me. Beyond writing that bash script, is there a simpler process that  I have overlooked?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at free file sync : https://www.freefilesync.org/ ?

You can set up the folders to sync, and export this as a script file. I've never had the need to have this done automatically, but I assume it should work if you write a simple script to call the generated free file sync script file every x amount of time. This should eliminate the need of you manually implementing syncing logic into your script.